# Do... Loop Until with multiple conditions

Tags: vba, excel, loops, conditional-statements

I have a quick question about which I did not find specific information on the web.
I want to perform a `Do...Loop Until` loop, but I would like to insert more than one condition at the end. I would like to do:

```
Do
    ' ...my code...
Loop Until [Condition 1] And [Condition 2] And....And [Condition n]`
```

Is this possible?

Thank you very much in advance,
Orlando

Comment: Can you not? Have you tried that? Do you get an error?

Comment: *I did not find specific information on the web* ...uh, I'm pretty sure `Do [statements] Loop Until [**Boolean Expression**]` is documented *somewhere*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The below example shows lazy evaluation implementation:

```
Do
    ' some operations
    Select Case False
        Case Condition1
        Case Condition2
        Case Condition3
        Case ConditionN
        Case Else Exit Do
    End Select
Loop
```

Such code allows to improve performance and speed up code execution. It evaluates conditions one by one until first false result only, if all conditions are true then it exits the loop, while conventional `And` operators evaluate all conditions regardless of the results.

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for the tip to speed up the calculations! :)

Answer (score 6):

It is possible indeed as if you were using "if " statement, for example:

```
Do Until rngCell.Value="" Or rngCell.Value="abc"
   DatePresent = (rngCell.Value = "RESP") Or (rngCell.Value ="Respiratory")
   Set rngCell = rngCell.Offset(1)
Loop
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `And` and/or `Or`:

```
Do
  'Your code
Loop until condition1 And condition2
```

`And` will continue all the time all conditions are met.
`Or` will continue when one or more of the conditions are met.

You can have any number of conditions.