# loop multiple conditions run time overflow

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

Hi I have the code below with multiple conditions for my loop. 
I tried my code using one condition at a time and it works but when I add the AND to have multiple conditions at once, I get a

> run time error 6 - overflow

Is there anyways around this ?

```
    J = 2
    Do Until ((SubActivity = fxlm.Range("B" & J).Value) And _
              (Plt = fxlm.Range("C" & J).Value) And _
              (Pl2 = fxlm.Range("D" & J).Value) And _
              (Pl2 = fxlm.Range("E" & J).Value) And _
              (Plb = fxlm.Range("F" & J).Value))
        J = J + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox J
```

Thanks

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900644/do-loop-until-with-multiple-conditions

Comment: @D.Pareek I did have a look at this before and even using the Select case false with my multiple conditions afterwards I still get a overflow error. It works when I just have one condition but not multiple

Comment: each condition have multiple "J" as possibilities but all these conditions together returns one answer only for j

Comment: I suspect you need more than one variable

Comment: Also, how are SubActivity and J declared? Are they Longs?

Comment: SubActivity and plt etc are all strings but thats not the problem.

Comment: I feel like when it finds one possible J for the first condition, the J found might not be a possible answer for condition 2, which gives me a run time error. I dont have this error when the first J found works on all conditions...

Comment: Is J declared as Integer or Long?

Comment: Even with J declared correctly there's nothing to stop this running off the end of the sheet if there's no match...

Comment: @TimWilliams running off the end wouldn't trigger an overflow though.  Causes 1004 Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald - I know that: just offering up another problem while the OP avoids telling us how J is declared...

Comment: `Pl2 = fxlm.Range("D" & J).Value) And Pl2 = fxlm.Range("E" & J).Value` - This will probably always be false unless D5 and E5 have identical values

Comment: why don't you find the last row of data so that you can use a for loop with limit boundaries for start and stop?  j can run away in this scenario right into empty cells and not stop.  You are not providing for termination if your conditional statement is false all the way through the sheet.