# Do Until Loop. One or another condition is met

Tags: excel, vba, windows

I am trying to create a loop to have Excel tell a DOS based system to search for a condition. If it doesn't find the condition I get stuck in an infinite loop. I have found many situations where a loop will go until it meets a condition. But is there a way to have it run until the condition is met OR an integer reaches a point? I am VERY new to VBA, so take my lack of knowledge lightly please.

I have tried several of the single condition guides, and purchased VBA for dummies, (not a great deal of help)

```
Sub Test ()
    DOS.readscreen StrLoop 3, 1, 4  

    Do Until StrLoop = "TXT"

    Loop
End Sub
```

I'm hoping to have an integer count to a certain point and if it reaches a point have it exit the loop. I am just uncertain of how to do it.

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: `do until strloop = "TXT" or i >= [number]`. Also very much as duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900644/do-loop-until-with-multiple-conditions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do... Loop Until with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900644/do-loop-until-with-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim StrLoop as string, i as long

Do
    DOS.readscreen StrLoop 3, 1, 4
    i = i + 1
Loop Until StrLoop = "TXT" or i = 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the variable strloop , until get to a value

```
dim i as long 
Do Until StrLoop = "TXT" or i = 1000
      DOS.readscreen StrLoop 3, 1, 4  
      i = i + 1 
Loop
```